# Formatting columns with Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a container containing a single row with two columns and am trying to format the left column so that it looks similar to a sidebar: full height and extending all the way to the left.
I used flex classes for this but ran into a couple problems:

- the columns doesn't extend all the way down
- the text "spreads" out instead of staying aligned in the center like before

Code without full height column:

```
<div class="container">   
            <form enctype=multipart/form-data action={{url_for('upload_file')}} method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 bg-light">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h4>Select a model:</h4>
                    <input type="radio" id="logreg" name="model" value="logreg" required>
                    <label for="male">Logistic regression</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="knn" name="model" value="knn">
                    <label for="male">K-nearest neighbors</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="randomforest" name="model" value="randomforest">
                    <label for="male">Random forest</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="svm" name="model" value="svm">
                    <label for="male">Kernel SVM</label><br>
                    <br>
                    <h4>Visuals</h4>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="mel" name="mel" value="mel">
                    <label for="mel"> Show Mel-Spectrogram</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chroma" name="chroma" value="chroma">
                    <label for="chroma"> Show Chroma Spectrogram</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tempo" name="tempo" value="tempo">
                    <label for="tempo"> Show Tempogram</label><br>
                    <br>
                    <p>See the project on <a href="link">GitLab</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h3>Music Genre Recognition</h3>
                    <p>We created an algorithm that can recognize the musical genre of an audio file.<br>
                        To try it, upload a file and choose a model, then click submit.</p>
                    <p>It can take up to a few minutes so be patient !</p>
                    <h3>Choose a file:</h3>
                    <br>
                    <input type="file" name="file" accept=".wav, .mp3" class="form-control" id="customFile" required/><br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

This is the html where I tried to make the left column full height:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100">   
    <form enctype=multipart/form-data action={{url_for('upload_file')}} method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
        <div class="row flex-fill">
            <div class="col-sm-4 bg-light d-flex flex-column flex-fill">
                <br>
                <br>
                <h4>Select a model:</h4>
                <input type="radio" id="logreg" name="model" value="logreg" required>
                <label for="male">Logistic regression</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="knn" name="model" value="knn">
                <label for="male">K-nearest neighbors</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="randomforest" name="model" value="randomforest">
                <label for="male">Random forest</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="svm" name="model" value="svm">
                <label for="male">Kernel SVM</label><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <h4>Visuals</h4>
                <input type="checkbox" id="mel" name="mel" value="mel">
                <label for="mel"> Show Mel-Spectrogram</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chroma" name="chroma" value="chroma">
                <label for="chroma"> Show Chroma Spectrogram</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="tempo" name="tempo" value="tempo">
                <label for="tempo"> Show Tempogram</label><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p>See the project on <a href="link">GitLab</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <br>
                <br>
                <h3>Music Genre Recognition</h3>
                <p>We created an algorithm that can recognize the musical genre of an audio file.<br>
                    To try it, upload a file and choose a model, then click submit.</p>
                <p>It can take up to a few minutes so be patient !</p>
                <h3>Choose a file:</h3>
                <br>
                <input type="file" name="file" accept=".wav, .mp3" class="form-control" id="customFile" required/><br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

How can I make this column full height and keep the text like in the first example ?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has some height utility classes that can stretch the height to be the same as the view port (`.min-vh-100`). If you apply this to the div with the `.row` class, flex should take care of stretching the columns to fill the space.

```
<div class="row min-vh-100">
  ...
</div>
```